# Condition for three buttons when pressed, it should call different functions and display text in same text widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, if-statement, dart, flutter-layout

I have made a number fact generating application,

I have three buttons `Random Trivia`, `Random Year`, `Random Date`. When Random trivia is clicked it generates random fact about that number, when random Year is clicked it generates random fact about year and similarly for Random date.

I want the condition for my buttons that- if `Random Year` is pressed, it should call the year function and display the fact in text widget & if `Random Date` is pressed, it should call the date function and display the fact in SAME text widget, and similarly for `Random Trivia`.

This is the function for `Random Trivia`-

```
void fetchDataForTrivia() async {
    http.Response response;
    response = await http.get(Uri.http('numbersapi.com', 'random/trivia'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(response.body);
      setState(() {
        factTrivia = response.body;
      });
    }
  }
```

Function for `Random Year`-

```
void fetchDataForYear() async {
    http.Response response;
    response = await http.get(Uri.http('numbersapi.com', 'random/year'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(response.body);
      setState(() {
        factYear = response.body;
      });
    }
  }
```

Function for `Random Date` -

```
void fetchDataForDate() async {
    http.Response response;
    response = await http.get(Uri.http('numbersapi.com', 'random/date'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(response.body);
      setState(() {
        factDate = response.body;
      });
    }
  }
```

This is Text Widget, for now it just displays `Random Trivia`-

```
Text(factTrivia.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.purple[400],
                  )),
```

And these are the buttons for 'RandomTrivia', 'Random Year', and 'Random Date' respectively-

```
ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    fetchDataForTrivia();
                  },
------------------

ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    fetchDataForYear();
                  },

------------------

ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    fetchDataForDate();
                  },
-----------------
```

Any help will be much appreciated:)

Comment: I dont understand what is the problem about, can you explain it?

Comment: @MiguelEscobarCalderon I have three buttons in my application, each display fact when they are pressed. The facts are about random year, date and random number. I want a condition where when a certain button is pressed lets say random year it should generate fact abt year in text widget, but when random date button is pressed it should display date fact in same Text widget

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure if I understand your Problem, but if I understand it correctly, you could do what you want by using just one variable (fact) instead of three (factDate, factTrivia and factYear). If you display the fact variable in your Text Widget, it will be updated to the correct fact whenever you click one of the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Right now your Text widget will only show factTrivia, no matter what button you press.
So change all your setStates (after each network call) to:

```
 setState(() {
        factTrivia = response.body;
      });
```

and maybe rename it to `factText` or something to make it more generic